# How to insert text and link_to within <p> in Slim

Tags: ruby, slim-lang

How can I insert a `link_to` alongside text in a `<p>` tag using Slim?

here is my `html.slim` view :

```
p.subtitle = t('.subtitle')
 = link_to 'Link', t('.title_link')
```

But it doesn't work

I also tried :

```
p.subtitle = t('.subtitle')
= link_to 'Link', t('.title_link')
```

This works but the link is outside the `<p>` tag

Comment: How does Rubocop relate to this question?

Comment: I guess the way to write it correctly

Comment: If it doesn't raise any warning then it's not relating to the question. I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `p.subtitle = t('.subtitle')` you close `p` tag immediately.
This code should work for you:

```
p.subtitle 
  = t('.subtitle')
  = link_to 'Link', t('.title_link')
```